# Regex Matching with Space

Tags: regex

I had a very simple question about regex matching, I want have "string" (ignore case) matched

in this case: `"thisisastring"`, nothing should be returned

in this case: `"this is a string"` a single match on "string" should be returned

Now I had `@"([S|s][T|t][R|r][I|i][N|n][G|g])"` as the regex, However it doesn't work correctly in the first case.

How should I write this regex?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it works for me see http://regex101.com/r/jK3tX3/3

Comment: it is also works for me...
([S|s][T|t][R|r][I|i][N|n][G|g]) just write this expression. may be u are putting double code(") in your expression

Comment: you could try this `(?i)string` also.

Comment: same here, works for me :)

Comment: How try with boundary `\b([S|s][T|t][R|r][I|i][N|n][G|g])`?

Comment: @suninsky no, it won't match the first one.

Comment: @ Avinash Raj I may misunderstand the question, i thought that not to match like first one.

Comment: Guys you realize that `[S|s]` is `S` or `|` or `s`, right? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`[S|s]` does not match what you seem to think**

Please note that `[S|s]` does not mean "match a `S` or a `s`". It means "match one character that is either a `S`, a `|` or a `s`". That's how things work inside a `[character class]`. To express an OR, you can use a non-capturing group: `(?:S|s)`. But `[Ss]` is all you need, and case-insensitivity is even better.

**Case-Insensitivity**

I'm going to assume we're using case-insensitive mode so we end up with a simpler regex. I assume you're in C# as it looks like you're using a verbatim string: `(?i)` will work. Another way to set case-insensitivity in C# would be `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`

**Option 1: boundary (close but no cigar)**

```
(?i)\bstring
```

This no longer matches `string` in `astring`. However, it matches `string` in `##string`, which you do not want.

**Option 2: lookbehind**

```
(?i)(?<=[ ])string
```

The lookbehind ensures that `string` is preceded by a space character. The brackets are optional, they help see the space.

**Option 3: `\K` (but not in C#)**

For engines that support it (Perl, PCRE, Ruby 2+):

```
(?i)[ ]\Kstring
```

The `\K` tells the engine to drop what was matched so far from the final match it returns